# How to read the attrbibute's value by an ExecuteStreamCommand arguments

Tags: minify, apache-nifi

i have this EvaluateJsonPath​ :

[image]

It generates something like this :

```
{"results":[{"term":"value1"},{"term":"value2"},{"term":"value3"}]}
```

This flowfile is then received by an ExecuteStreamCommand :

[image]
​

I want to pass this flowfile as an arguments in my process, i've already tried ${terms} and {$terms} as showed above, but it doesn't work..

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remis,

You can pass the entire flow file as arguments using **"ExtractText"** processor.

```
EvaluateJsonPath-->ExtractText-->ExecuteStreamCommand
```

In that extracttext,you have to add new property like below.

```
JsonContent:(.*)
```

In that JsonContent having entire flowfile in which from evaluateJsonPath processor.

After getting you can use that in **ExecuteStreamCommand** by **${JsonContent}**